# Generic function names in java 8

Tags: java, generics

I have few entities in my app and I want to have a functionality where I can generically set few properties on them when user tries to save them.

For this, I have attempted writing  a utility class as follows:

```
public class IrisUserUtil<T> {

IrisUserRepository irisUserRepository;

public IrisUserUtil(IrisUserRepository irisUserRepository){
    this.irisUserRepository = irisUserRepository;
}

public <S extends T> S populate(S entity) {

    //IrisUser irisuser = irisUserRepository.findOne(entity.getIrisUserId());
    //entity.setFirstName(irisuser.getFirstName());
    //entity.setLastName(irisuser.getLastName());
    return entity;

}
}
```

This I will call just before my `repository.save()` ; Here I am looking for correct way to call functions like `entity.getIrisUserId()` etc on the passed parameter that is "entity". Of course, this is not working.

please suggest why?

Comment: What's the bound to `S` and `T`, does the above code compile?

Comment: yes, edited the question as par @Assafs , like this
 public class IrisUserUtil<T> {...
it compliles

Answer (score 1):

maybe with `<S extends Entity>` and not T what is T here ?
How the compilater know that S is something extending the Entity class (or an other base class) ?

```
public <S extends T> S populate(S entity)
```

In your code S and T are somethings extending Object, the compilater can't known your methods getIrisUserId(), getFirstName() etc...

I think you have to remove your generic T in the class and just do

```
public <S extends Entity> S populate(S entity)
```

or (but useless and more complicated)

```
public class IrisUserUtil<T extends Entity> {
```

and

```
public <S extends T> S populate(S entity)
```

or in a simple way no need to use generic types just do (but you have to cast the returned entity with the concrete type)

```
public Entity populate(Entity entity) {

 ...   
return entity;

}
```

in my example Entity is your entities abstract base class

Comment: T is generic Type,  like this :  public class IrisUserUtil<T>

Comment: i know generics but the post was edited because before the class definition was public class IrisUserUtil { without T

Comment: Are you suggesting, that I should create a class called "Entity" and have abstract methods like getName, setName and let other extend it,so when their instance is passed to this method, it works!!

I was not in favour of creating an abstract class, is there any way java can evaluate method reference based on string and call it

Comment: if you have just IrisUser to manage in this code why use generic types ?

Comment: i think an abstract class are fine in your case (or an interface if no need to share code between your inherited entities). evaluate a method based on a string is a bad practice (no autocompletion in your ide, no compilater verfication etc.) in some rare case you can use reflection with java.lang.reflect

Comment: "is there any way java can evaluate method reference based on string and call it" Yes, but try to avoid it unless you really can't.